# Fast Ethernet but slow Wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, performance, internet

Over the months, I have seen my wifi speed slow down drastically. I used to get around 70-80mbps Down and 80-90 Up with 5 ping, now I'm getting 10-30 Mbps and 30 Up. I have a good router and modem, I even called the internet provider, to see if they were doing something shady.
I first tried disconnecting everything except my phone and it actually worked and I had my full speed, but once I tried it again, a few days later, I still had low speeds with only my phone connected. I tried searching for the device that was pulling the bandwidth but found nothing.
The problems are very inconsistent and point to different sources. My internet provider tech support told me that I had a problem with my router, I already have the new one in my cart ready to but, but I don't want to spend money on something and have the same problem.

Comment: Try updating the router firmware. That may help and provide some stability.  Also delete and remake the wireless setup in the router.

Comment: Try also a factory reset of the router.

Comment: And, for good measure, just change the router password in case you have a neighbour sucking up your bandwidth

Comment: See this question: https://superuser.com/questions/799254/ethernet-is-fast-but-wi-fi-is-slow?rq=1

Comment: WiFi is a shared media. May be some neighbor router is now using the same frequencies your WiFi used which causes collisions and thus lower the speed.